# C++ .txt read in issues. getline reading full file

Tags: c++11, ifstream, getline

first of all, forgive my code for being ugly. The tons of ideas I've been given to try to fix this code have jumbled it up after all the potential solutions that haven't worked. Basically, I'm coding a Hearthstone rip-off that reads in two .txt files with card information and battles them to see which player wins. The issue is that when I'm trying to save the player's name (the first line in the files), it saves the whole file instead of just the first line. When I have managed to fix that, the for loop used to save the information for the card objects (format: card name, card power, card health) does not get saved properly for some reason. Any help would be appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for two days and nothing has fully solved the problem. I'll attach the read in files first before the code.

Disclaimer: It's a lot of lines and I'm sorry about that. Also I think the problem could be that my Mac is not saving the .txt in a format that has the right line endings. I'm using XCode as my IDE. Thank you so much to whomever is willing to help!

File1:

```
The Innkeeper
3
Tunnel Trogg
1
3
Neptulon
7
7
Fire Elemental
6
5
```

File2:

```
Malfurion
3
Leper Gnome
2
1
Aviana
5
5
Cenarius
5
8
```

Main:

```
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter file name of the first player: " << endl;
string inFile = "";
getline(cin, inFile);

Player* p1 = new Player(inFile);

cout << "Now enter the file name of the second player: " << endl;
getline(cin, inFile);
Player* p2 = new Player(inFile);

p1->battle(*p2);

delete p1;
delete p2;

return 0;
}
```

Player Header:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <fstream>

#ifndef Player_h
#define Player_h
using namespace std;
class Player
{
private:
    string playerName;
    int numCards;
    Card ** cards;
    int wins = 0;
public:
    Player(std::string inFile);
    void battle(Player p2);
    Card* getCard(int counter);
    ~Player();
};
#endif /* Player_h */
```

Card Header:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef Card_h
#define Card_h

using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
    Card();
    string getName();
    int getPower();
    int getHealth();
    void setName(string newName);
    void setPower(int newPower);
    void setHealth(int newHealth);

    Card* duel(Card&);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Card& c);
    friend bool operator==(Card& p1Card, Card& p2Card);
private:
    string name;
    int power;
    int health;
};
#endif /* Card_h */
```

Player Source:

```
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

Player::Player(string inFile)
{
    ifstream in(inFile, ios::in);\
    if (!in)
    {
        cerr << "There was a problem opening the file. Sorry, try again!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    getline(in, playerName);
    cout << playerName << endl;
    in>>numCards;

    playerName = "";
    numCards = 0;
    cards = new Card* [numCards];

    string tempName = "";
    int tempPower = 0;
    int tempHealth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<numCards; i++)
    {
        in.ignore();
        cards[i] = new Card();
        getline(in, tempName);
        cout << "in for loop: " << endl;
        cout << tempName << ",";
        cards[i]->setName(tempName);
        in >> tempPower;
        in.ignore();
        cout << tempPower << ",";
        cards[i]->setPower(tempPower);
        in >> tempHealth;
        cout << tempHealth << "             done"<< endl;
        cards[i]->setHealth(tempHealth);
    }
}

void Player::battle(Player p2)
{
    int draws = 0;

    cout << "Let the battle begin!" << endl;
    cout << numCards << endl;

    if (wins > p2.wins)
    {
        cout << playerName << " wins over " << p2.playerName << ", " << wins << " to " << p2.wins;

        if (draws == 0)
        {
            cout << " and no ties." << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << " and " << draws << " ties." << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (p2.wins > wins)
    {
        cout << p2.playerName << " wins over " << playerName << ", " << p2.wins << " to " << wins;

        if (draws == 0)
        {
            cout << " and no ties." << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << " and " << draws << " ties." << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (p2.wins == wins)
    {
        cout << "It is a draw between " << playerName << " and " << p2.playerName << ", with " << wins << " for each and ";
        if (draws == 0)
        {
            cout << "no ties." << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << draws << " ties." << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Here are the detailed results:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
    {
        cout << *cards[i] << " vs. " << *p2.cards[i] << " - ";

        if (*cards[i] == *p2.cards[i])
        {
            cout << "It is a draw." << endl;
        }

        else if (cards[i]->duel(*p2.cards[i]) == NULL)
        {
            cout << "It is a draw." << endl;
        }

        else if (*cards[i]->duel(*p2.cards[i]) == *p2.cards[i])
        {
            cout << p2.cards[i]->getName() << "wins for " << p2.playerName << "." << endl;
        }

        else if (*cards[i]->duel(*p2.cards[i]) == *cards[i])
        {
            cout << cards[i]->getName() << "wins for " << playerName << "." << endl;
        }
    }
}


Player::~Player()
{
    if (cards != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
        {
            if (cards[i] != nullptr)
            {
                delete cards[i];
                cards[i] = NULL;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Card Source:

```
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;

Card::Card()
{
    name = "";
    power = 0;
    health = 0;
}

string Card::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Card::getPower()
{
    return power;
}

int Card::getHealth()
{
    return health;
}

void Card::setName(string newName)
{
    name = newName;
}

void Card::setPower(int newPower)
{
    power = newPower;
}

void Card::setHealth(int newHealth)
{
    health = newHealth;
}

Card* Card::duel(Card& otherCard)
{
    if ((otherCard.getHealth() - this->getPower() <=0) && (getHealth() - otherCard.getPower() <= 0))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    else if ((otherCard.getHealth() - this->getPower() >0) && (getHealth() - otherCard.getPower() >0))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    else if (otherCard.getHealth() - this->getPower() <=0)
    {
        return this;
    }

    else if (this->getHealth() - otherCard.getPower() <=0)
    {
        return &otherCard;
    }

    return NULL;
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Card& c)
{
    o << c.getName() << " (" << c.power << ", " << c.health << ") " << endl;

    return o;
}

bool operator==(Card& p1Card, Card& p2Card)
{
    if (p1Card.health == p2Card.health &&
        p1Card.power == p2Card.power &&
        p1Card.name == p2Card.name)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right. It can read the Player's name and the card numbers, but your codes showed below:

```
in>>numCards;
playerName = "";
numCards = 0;
cards = new Card* [numCards];
```

at first, it read the num of card and store it to numCards, it is right.
next, you clear the value of the numCards, then, you lost the num of the Card, so the codes followed it are executed with `numCards == 0`
You can just comment the line `numCards = 0`, and your code is executed right.